# More efficient way of doing row operations with multiple boolean indexing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df` with the shape `(7694079, 4)`. The columns are `['CompanyName', 'MetricValue', 'AsofDate', 'FiscalYear']`. For each `FiscalYear`, there are multiple `AsOfDate`.

A sample:

> ```
>          CompanyName  MetricValue   AsOfDate  FiscalYear
> 49  360Networks Inc.     -295.945 2001-03-31        2000
> 50  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-04-30        2000
> 51  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-05-31        2000
> 52  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-06-30        2000
> 53  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-07-31        2000
> 54  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-08-31        2000
> 55  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-09-30        2000
> 56  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-10-31        2000
> 57  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-11-30        2000
> 58  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-12-31        2000
> ```

My goal is to add a bool column to `df`, named `cleanse_filter`, labeling the rows where `AsOfDate` is one of the first 6 per `FiscalYear` for each company.

This code works, but takes 16 seconds to run for each company, and for > 22k companies, that will take forever. Any ideas on how to improve the efficiency?

```
for company in df['CompanyName'].unique():
    for year in df[df['CompanyName'] == company]['FiscalYear'].unique():
        condition = (df['CompanyName'] == company)&(df['FiscalYear'] == year)    
        date_thr = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[condition]['AsOfDate']).sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)[5]
        df.loc[condition, 'cleanse_filter'] = df.loc[condition, 'AsOfDate'].apply(lambda x: True if x < date_thr else False)
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to question?

Comment: My solution was a bit changed, can you test it with your real data?

Comment: Works wonders, thanks!

Comment: Super, good news!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try rewrite your solution:

```
def f(x):
    try:
       date_thr = x.iat[5]
    except:
        date_thr = x.max()
    return date_thr

s = (df.sort_values(['AsOfDate'])
       .groupby(['CompanyName', 'FiscalYear'], sort=False)['AsOfDate']
       .transform(f))
df['cleanse_filter'] = df['AsOfDate'] < s
print (df)
         CompanyName  MetricValue   AsOfDate  FiscalYear  cleanse_filter
49  360Networks Inc.     -295.945 2001-03-31        2000            True
50  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-04-30        2000            True
51  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-05-31        2000            True
52  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-06-30        2000            True
53  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-07-31        2000            True
54  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-08-31        2000           False
55  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-09-30        2000           False
56  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-10-31        2000           False
57  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-11-30        2000           False
58  360Networks Inc.      101.992 2001-12-31        2000           False
```